# class Duck which creates randomly initialized numbers for each duck object

Tags: python, class, object

I'm writing a Duck class such that each Duck object created contains wingspan and weight field variables. Each of these should be initialized randomly for every duck. Wingspans should be initialized to a random float in the range [80.0,100.0]cm. Weight should be initialized randomly in the range [0.7,1.6]kg.

i thought this would be simple but my output is completely wrong for some reason:

```
import random
class Duck:

    wingspan = round(random.uniform(80.0, 100.0), 1)
    weight = round(random.uniform(0.7,1.6), 2)
```

i'm looking for an output similar to this:

```
>>> duck1 = Duck()
>>> print(duck1.wingspan)
  83.2
>>> print(duck1.weight)
  0.93
>>> duck2 = Duck()
>>> print(duck2.wingspan)
  97.5
>>> print(duck2.weight)
  1.32
```

but i keep getting the same output for wingspan and weight for both ducks:

```
>>> duck1 = Duck()
>>> print(duck1.wingspan)
  83.2
>>> print(duck1.weight)
  0.93
>>> duck2 = Duck()
>>> print(duck2.wingspan)
  83.2
>>> print(duck2.weight)
  0.93
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've made class variables, and not instance variables. This means that these are the same values for *all* instances of the class. Simply assign them to the instance:

```
import random
class Duck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wingspan = round(random.uniform(80.0, 100.0), 1)
        self.weight = round(random.uniform(0.7,1.6), 2)
```